# Calculate WMAPE for groupby object with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, forecast

I have a dataframe called "revenue" that looks like this:

[image]

I want to calculate WMAPE for each month.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WMAPE

Wikipedia suggests that WMAPE is one scalar number, and I'm struggling to figure out how to calculate that for a groupby object.  I know that I have to start by doing this:

```
revenue.groupby('month')
```

To calculate WMAPE without group by month, here is my code:

```
sum(abs(revenue['actual'] - revenue['forecast'])) / sum(abs(revenue['actual']))
Out[1]: 0.12206572769953052
```

How do I do this for the groupby object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your calculation code to `groupby.apply`:

```py
revenue.groupby('month').apply(lambda x:sum(abs(x['actual'] - x['forecast'])) / sum(abs(x['actual'])))
# month
# July    0.109890
# June    0.131148
# dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works using sklearn:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error

revenue.groupby('month').apply(func = lambda x: mean_absolute_percentage_error(x['actual'], x['forecast']))
```